# Error when checking input: expected conv2d_4_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (32, 32)

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib, conv-neural-network

I am working on a image recognition system in CNN. 
The train and test data are input as follows:

```
trainDataGen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rotation_range = 5,
        width_shift_range = 0.1,
        height_shift_range = 0.1,
        rescale = 1.0/255,
        shear_range = 0.2,
        zoom_range = 0.2,       
        horizontal_flip = False,
        fill_mode = 'nearest')

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
trainGenerator = trainDataGen.flow_from_directory(
            r"Dataset/Train",
            target_size = (32,32),
            batch_size = 32,
            color_mode = "grayscale",
            class_mode = "categorical")
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
            r"Dataset/Test",
            target_size=(32,32),
            batch_size=32,
            color_mode = "grayscale",
            class_mode= 'categorical')
```

The 4 layered CNN is implemented that starts as follows:

```
model = Sequential()

#Layer1----------------------------------------------------------
model.add(Convolution2D(filters = 32,
            kernel_size = (3,3),
            strides = 1,
            activation = "relu",
            input_shape = (32,32,3)))
```

The training is done successfully as follows:

```
#Fit model on the loaded dataset---------
res=model.fit_generator(
        trainGenerator,
        epochs = 25,
        steps_per_epoch = 2444,
        validation_data = validation_generator,
        validation_steps = 432
        )
```

Now I am trying to test the test data by:

```
#Compile Model---------------------------
model.compile(optimizer = "adam",
        loss = "categorical_crossentropy",
        metrics = ["accuracy"])

res= model.evaluate_generator(validation_generator)
```

This shows the error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_4_input to have shape (32, 32, 3) but got array with shape (32, 32, 1)
```

As even after a lot of try I could not run opencv, I am trying matplotlib instead.

```
# Python program to read 
# image using matplotlib 

# importing matplotlib modules 
import matplotlib.image as mpimg 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

# Read Images 
img = mpimg.imread('pic.png') 

# Output Images 
plt.imshow(img)
```

This works perfectly. Now I try to predict what image thus pic.png is. I try:

```
lists = model.predict(img)
```

This shows error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_4_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (32, 32)
```

Can anyone please help on how I can change the input size?

Comment: can you try: `lists = model.predict(np.array(img).reshape(-1, 32, 32, 1))`

Answer (score 0):

I think the image you are trying to test with is a gray scale image, which means that it has a single channel, that's why you are getting this 32x32 or 32x32x1 error.

In the case of the matplotlib code, the solution is to reshape the (32, 32) image using numpy to (32, 32, 1), duplicate the third dimension three times:

```
import numpy as np
img = np.reshape(img, (32, 32, 1))
img = np.concatenate([img, img, img], axis=2)
```

I think you must change the color_mode from gray_scale to rgb in you validation_generator